# what are the two numbers for an instruction location in objdump of a kernel module?

Tags: debugging, gcc, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

While doing a debug for a linux device driver, I met with a situation the OS is killed with some messages. Because it doesn't come to the shell prompt, I can't run `dmesg` and I just have to restart the machine (it's a arm64 virtual machine). I don't know why sometimes the machine crashes without just killing the program.(most of times, it returns to the shell)
The program died with this message below(just shown a part for this question).

```
csr seen at app..
0 0 0 f 4225a8 4228a8 443040 0 
[  743.787778] Unable to handle kernel access to user memory outside uaccess routines at virtual address 0000000000442f00
[  743.790613] Mem abort info:
[  743.790955]   ESR = 0x9600000f
[  743.791572]   EC = 0x25: DABT (current EL), IL = 32 bits
[  743.792437]   SET = 0, FnV = 0
[  743.792980]   EA = 0, S1PTW = 0
[  743.793676] Data abort info:
[  743.794119]   ISV = 0, ISS = 0x0000000f
[  743.794625]   CM = 0, WnR = 0
[  743.795318] user pgtable: 4k pages, 48-bit VAs, pgdp=0000000075b0f000
[  743.796458] [0000000000442f00] pgd=000000006fe06003, pud=000000006fe0c003, pmd=000000006fe10003, pte=00e800004f108f53
[  743.799097] Internal error: Oops: 9600000f [#1] SMP
[  743.800477] Modules linked in: axpu_ldd_kc(OE) nls_iso8859_1 dm_multipath scsi_dh_rdac scsi_dh_emc scsi_dh_alua qemu_fw_cfg sch_fq_codel ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs zstd_compress raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor xor_neon raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear crct10dif_ce ghash_ce sm4_ce sm4_generic sm3_ce sm3_generic sha3_ce sha3_generic sha512_ce sha512_arm64 sha2_ce sha256_arm64 sha1_ce virtio_net net_failover failover virtio_blk aes_neon_bs aes_neon_blk aes_ce_blk crypto_simd cryptd aes_ce_cipher
[  743.808604] CPU: 2 PID: 1179 Comm: test_axpu_app Tainted: G           OE     5.4.0-77-generic #86-Ubuntu
[  743.809607] Hardware name: QEMU QEMU Ab21q Virtual Machine, BIOS 0.0.0 02/06/2015
[  743.811097] pstate: 20400005 (nzCv daif +PAN -UAO)
[  743.813870] pc : axpu_ioctl+0x3ec/0xb54 [axpu_ldd_kc]
[  743.814477] lr : axpu_ioctl+0x3cc/0xb54 [axpu_ldd_kc]
[  743.815031] sp : ffff800013733c90
[  743.815511] x29: ffff800013733c90 x28: ffff00002fb04b00 
[  743.816277] x27: 0000000000000000 x26: ffff800009243448 
[  743.816855] x25: 0000000000000000 x24: ffff800009243470 
[  743.817448] x23: ffff000027373000 x22: ffff8000092433d0 
[  743.818144] x21: ffff8000092433d8 x20: ffff000017ab0a40 
[  743.818782] x19: ffff8000092454c0 x18: 0000000000000001 
[  743.819493] x17: 0000000000000000 x16: 0000000000000000 
[  743.820156] x15: ffff00002fb05028 x14: ffffffffffffffff 
[  743.820789] x13: 0000000000000000 x12: ffff800011db3000 
[  743.821422] x11: ffff800011b9e000 x10: 0000000000000000 
[  743.822018] x9 : 0000000000000004 x8 : 0000000000000214 
[  743.822593] x7 : 0000000000000001 x6 : ffff800011db3000 
[  743.823179] x5 : ffff00003fdb5248 x4 : 0000000000000007 
[  743.823857] x3 : 0000000000000000 x2 : 0000000000000008 
[  743.824621] x1 : ffff000023002200 x0 : 0000000000442f00 
[  743.825939] Call trace:
[  743.826397]  axpu_ioctl+0x3ec/0xb54 [axpu_ldd_kc]
[  743.828010]  do_vfs_ioctl+0xc64/0xe60
```

At the bottom I see the call trace starting and it says it crashed near `axpu_ioctl+0x3ec/0xb54`. `axpu_ioctl` is the function name, but what are those two numbers? I can guess one is the offset from the axpu_ioctl but can't understand why there two and which is which..
If I can know the exact code location, it would be very easy to find the source line with problem, but I can't exactly understand the two numbers.

Comment: I think the one after the slash is notionally the function size in bytes. (Note that this size will include the bodies of functions that the compiler decided to call inline.)

Comment: @IanAbbott Hi, thanks again. I could check for only one function and it looks like it. But there is a slight difference (0x10) in the function size.

Comment: The Oops message suggests problems with user memory accesses in the driver. As a first step I would install the *sparse* package and build the driver with `make C=1` (the `C=1` enables "sparse" checking). The various kernel source code pointer tags such as `__user` for user memory pointers and `__iomem` for memory-mapped I/O pointers will be checked for consistent usage.

Comment: Those two numbers are: _offset of the trapped instruction_ and _size_ of the function.